# jQuery not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have a search page for a database at http://www.iiserpune.ac.in/~coee/histome/searchadv.php where I use jQuery to dynamically provide another option when 'Disease' is selected. This works fine on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari but breaks down in IE. Is there a workaround for this?

The jquery code is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#select").change(function() {

    if ($(this).val() == 'disease') {
        $("#value").html("for <select id='filter' name='filter'><option value='%%'>All...</option><option value='histone' >Histone and Histone variants</option><option value='modification' >Post translational modifications</option><option id='Sub' value='enzyme' >Histone Modifying Enzymes</option></select>");
    }
    else {
        $("#value").html('');
        $("#value").css("background-color", "white");
        $("#value").css("color", "black");
    }
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code?

Comment: I have added the code above. If it is working for you that is great. When I select diseases and then say 'All...' among the second drop down menu and enter cancer in the text field and hit search, I get zero results in IE9 and some 200 odd results in other browsers.

Comment: well, the jQuery that provides the second option when 'disease' is selected: works. 
It was not clear for me that you were asking about the form post instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to bind event on element that doesnt exist. Try using:

```js
$('#select').live('change', function() {
   ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not seem to work. It did not work even on other browsers.

Comment: Well, maybe the fact. That you've got 2 elements with same id can break your script execution. Have you tried using classes, rather than ids for select identification?

Comment: Thanks, I changed the id so there aren't two elements with the same id. I still can't get it to work with IE. Apparently, the code inside the <div> is displayed but it doesn't get included when I submit. Thus, there is no '&filter=' in the URL when using IE.

Comment: Check this example i posted on jsfiddle. Look at your javascript console log to see what parameters go with POST request.
http://jsfiddle.net/nChCT/2/